# How to give a linux container on ChromeOS an outside accesible ip

Tags: network-programming

I am trying to host the most basic python flask server over the linux container on ChromeOS.
The flask server hosts no problem, i have more of a problem with accessing it.

The thing is that the linux container runs over, by my understanding a private network with the ip 100.115.x.x
Hosting the flask server over this ip is working but somewhat obviously, not accessible over other devices over the network but how do i give it a accessible ip so that the server is accessible by it.

The `ip ad` command gives following output

```
5: eth0@if6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:16:3e:88:24:7c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 100.115.92.195/28 brd 100.115.92.207 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::216:3eff:fe88:247c/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution was quite simple and i was apparently just using the wrong questions for my research.
For those having the same problem and not knowing how to solve it, here is my solution:

In the developer section of the advanced settings you go to port forwarding and port forward port 5000, which is the standard port for your flask app (the ip address is not required as it is only the that is forwarded).
The you run the script under the ip of your linux container and can access it over the ip of your chromebook

So in the shell you would get displayed that the server runs on
`http://100.115.92.195:5000`
but you would use
`http://192.168.60.70:5000`
for example. Use whatever is displayed to be the ip of the chromebook.